# D3.js starter(noob): How to get a D3 example from bl.ocks.org/mbostock working?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm completely new to JavaScript and D3.js. I have done some work in recent days, like making appropriate json object for the graph, and wanted to know how to get [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045) running in particular. Any direction to appropriate links would be great, though I would prefer to get an answer in the form of any missing tags or any details I need to take care of.

Note: I have to run it locally, not on server-client model.

Update: I have done it a lot of times what Bill answered, it didn't work. So I tried again and I opened the console in browser to check for any errors. Got this:

```
Failed to load resource:       file://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js

net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

index.html:23 Uncaught ReferenceError: d3 is not defined
```

Comment: you can use jsfiddle / plunkr or codepen.

Comment: Thanks for the advice cyril, another friend recommended that to me. It is not working either. Still shows the blank screen which I get while running it locally. I also tried using a custom JSON object declared in the script itself to avoid dependencies on the JSON file given in that example, no luck...

Comment: see here made plunk for you http://plnkr.co/edit/NjCAF3kFh7QuXy2zcdun?p=preview

Comment: Hey thanks man, but I realized something from the errors I found in the console. It was giving errors due to cross referencing i.e. one file had to imported via http request and other was locally present. Any way out to solve this issue ?? I want to run it on my own machine rather than plunkr. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is that you cannot access files on your computer from javascript using `file://` (think that people could access all your file...).

So you have to use `<script src="address/d3.js"></script>` here, `address` correspond to the address of your server (`http://domain.com` or `http://localhost`) or the relative path.

For example, you can download d3.js next to your html file (same folder) and just type `<script src="d3.js"></script>`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

1. Go to https://gist.github.com/mbostock/4062045
2. Click on the Raw button next to index.html
3. Copy everything and paste it into a file on your computer called **index.html**
4. Go back and click on the Raw button next to the .json file
5. Copy everything and paste it into a file on your computer called **miserables.json** (make sure this file is in the same folder as index.html)
6. Double click on index.html, it should open in your browser

Comment: Probably due to the local file access.  Read http://www.chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/.

Comment: Hey, check the update I posted in the question. Thanks for helping out